# waiting for task completion inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to wait till the execution of one loop is completed in below code.Dont intended to process next item in list until one is done. How to ensure that execution inside foreach loop is completed once at a time or one loop at a time in the below scenario

Please note, this is a sample code only to demonstrate the issue, I know that if I remove the Task.Run from for each loop, it may work, but I need to have that task.Run in the foreach loop for some reason in my code.

```
List<int> Items = new List<int>();
Items.Add(1);
Items.Add(2);
Items.Add(3);

foreach(var itm in Items)
{
 Task.Run(() =>
       {
       MyFunction(itm);
       });

//  I want to wait here till one execution is complete, e.g till execution of Item with Value 1 is completed,  
//I dont' intend to execute next item value of 2 until processing with value 1 is completed.

}

private void MyFunction(int value)
{    
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
  MyFunction2(value);

    });

}


private void MyFunction2 (int number)
{
// do some ops 
// update UI

}
```

Comment: What's the point of using threads if you want sequential execution?

Comment: @Ripi2 not blocking the UI thread, I guess.

Comment: @Adam Stafa, Absolutely right, not blocking the UI thread is the intent

Comment: What about using [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netframework-4.8) in the thread?

Comment: Task.Run returns a Task object that represents that work. You need to call Wait on that.

Comment: you have to show how this links up to your GUI. Also tell us what kind of project it is (WinForms, WPF, ...)

Comment: And in all case, you can't update the UI in MyFunction2 ()

Answer (score 2):

Use async await. `await` allows you to wait for a `Task` to finish without blocking the thread (thus your application won't freeze)

```cs
foreach(var itm in Items)
{
    await MyFunction(itm);
}

// you must return Task to await it. void won't work
private Task MyFunction(int value)
{
    // Task.Run is preferred over Task.Factory.StartNew,
    // although it won't make any difference
    return Task.Run(() => MyFunction2(value));
}
```

Also don't forget to make the method containing the foreach loop `async Task`. You can await Tasks only in `async` methods. Return type should be `Task`, so you can later await it and possibly catch exceptions. Avoid `async void`, unless the method is an event handler.

```cs
public async Task Foo()
{
    foreach(var itm in Items)
    {
        await MyFunction(itm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid `async void` in all but a few cases.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. async void truly is a source of terrible headaches.

Answer (score -3):

Task.Run returns a Task object that represents that work. You need to call Wait on that.

```
 var myTask = Task.Run(() =>
   {
   MyFunction(itm);
   });
  myTask.Wait();
```

Comment: What's the point of doing this? Task.Wait will block the UI thread, just like calling `MyFunction` synchronously without creating the Task.

Comment: OP wrote "Dont intended to process next item in list until one is done."